# classes which are not part of the public API

Tags: java, api

How do I protect classes which are used in another package (from classes which don't inherit) to be instantiated from the outside? Is this even possible in Java?

Answer (score 1):

make constructor protected

```
public class ProtectClass {

    protected ProtectClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm not inheriting. Let's say package `org.sirix.node` with node implementations and `org.sirix.access` for API implementations of transactions. Then, in a perfect world within org.sirix.access the node package should be visible but not from the outside.

Comment: a Protected constructor can access from package too, u don't need to inherit!! i think you have to use one package for both classes and make the constructors of node package protected and instantiate them from access classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, abstract classes can't be instantiated, but that may not be what you're looking for... I've never heard of this being possible.

Comment: No, for instance in a tree-structure, nodes should only be created from within a transaction. Using the node-constructors is really pointless as the nodes are not viewable from within any transaction and not persitable, but it is possible to instantiate nodes because the classes have to be `public`, as the transaction-implementations are in another package.

Comment: There's not much you can do if they need to be instantiated from a separate package. Sorry. Unless there is some way to have the nodes be a protected class and make the class that needs to instantiate them a friend class. But I have no idea if that's actually possible and friend classes open up other potential issues...

Comment: Thanks, do you know if anything is going to come with Java8? Hm, I'm seriously considering mixing Java and Scala ;-)